# Create JSON result with certain structures

Tags: android, json

I'm developing an Android application, I need to create a Json resul that contains some data in a certain structures.

This is what that i must obtain:

```
 {  
      "speedtest":"10Mbit/s",
      "httpRequest":[  
         {  
            "url":"www.google.com",
            "statusCode":"200"
         },
         {  
            "url":"www.google.com",
            "statusCode":"200"
         },
         {  
            "url":"www.google.com",
            "statusCode":"200"
         }
      ],
      "traceroute":[  
         {  
            "url":"www.google.com",
            "nodes":[  
               "45.34.222.11",
               "232.43.54.32"
            ]
         },
         {  
            "url":"www.google.com",
            "nodes":[  
               "45.34.222.11",
               "232.43.54.32"
            ]
         },
         {  
            "url":"www.google.com",
            "nodes":[  
               "45.34.222.11",
               "232.43.54.32"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
```

And this is the code that i wrote, but it doesn't work properly and i dont understan why.

```
public class JsonBuilder {
    String LogTag = "LogTags";

    JsonBuilder(long downSpeed, ArrayList < String > ReqTest) {
        long ds = downSpeed;
        ArrayList < String > rt = ReqTest;

        JSONArray ja = null;
        JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject speedData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            speedData.put("speedtest", ds+"Mbit/s");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.wtf(LogTag, "JSON exception SpeedTest", e);
        }

        JSONObject HttpData = new JSONObject();
        String[] req_split;

        for (int i = 0; i < rt.size(); i++) {
            req_split = rt.get(i).split(";", 2);
            try {
                HttpData.put("url", req_split[0]);
                HttpData.put("statusCode", req_split[1]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.wtf(LogTag, "JSON exception", e);
            }
        }

         ja = new JSONArray();
         ja.put(HttpData);


        try {
            mainJson.put("httpRequest", ja);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.wtf(LogTag, "JSON" + mainJson.toString());

    }
}
```

I have created a part of json now i don't know how to merge it

Comment: `but it doesn't work properly and i dont understan why` which problem u are getting?

Comment: I need to create this exatly structures:
{  
      "speedtest":"10Mbit/s",
      "httpRequest":[  
         {  
            "url":"www.google.com",
            "statusCode":"200"
         },
         {  
            "url":"www.google.com",
            "statusCode":"200"
         },
         {  
            "url":"www.google.com",
            "statusCode":"200"
         }

I don't know how to add speedData to the main object to create the final JSON

Comment: Do speedData.put("httpRequest", ja);

Answer (score 2):

The better and easy way to do is to create three entity classes like this

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class Example {

    @Expose(serialize = true)
    String speedtest;
    @Expose(serialize = true)
    List<httpRequest> httpRequest;
    @Expose(serialize = true)
    List<traceroute> traceroute;
}

public class httpRequest {
    @Expose(serialize = true)
    String url;
    @Expose(serialize = true)
    String statusCode;
}


public class traceroute {
    @Expose(serialize = true)
    String url;
    @Expose(serialize = true)
    List<String> nodes;
}
```

Then fill your objects with the data;
and after that convert your Example's (Parent class) object to Json using gson library like this

```
String json = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().serializeNulls().create().toJson(expamleClassObject);
```

Use the following link to import gson library in your app using Android studio

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

Comment: If your problem is solved then make this an Answer so that other people can easily solve their these types of problems

Comment: So if i understand should i import gson library in my project, create a java class that contains your code (3 classes), and use it to "build" in real time my json, right ?

Comment: Ok i have create a java class with your code, now i have a problem to understand how to use it, could you make me one example ?

(I never use gson)

With your code could i obtain the json that i wrote in my message ?

Comment: are you using android studio? write compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' in build.gradle file under dependencies tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this if you want it do with JSON Object

```
try {
                JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();

                JSONArray httpRequest = new JSONArray();
                    JSONObject httpRequestObject = new JSONObject();
                    httpRequestObject.put("url", "www.google.com");
                    httpRequestObject.put("url", "www.google.com");
                httpRequest.put(httpRequestObject);

                JSONArray traceroute = new JSONArray();
                    JSONObject tracerouteObject = new JSONObject();
                    tracerouteObject.put("url", "www.google.com");
                        JSONArray nodes=new JSONArray();
                        nodes.put("45.34.222.11");
                        nodes.put("232.43.54.32");

                mainObject.put("speedtest","10Mbit/s");
                mainObject.put("httpRequest",httpRequest);
                mainObject.put("traceroute",traceroute);
                Log.e("json",mainObject.toString());

            }catch (Exception e){

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As in required JSON, main `JSONObject` contains both `speedtest` and `httpRequest` `JSONArray`, so instead of adding `httpRequest` in `mainJson` JSONObject add it in `speedData` JSONObject like:

```
 speedData.put("httpRequest", ja);
```

Now use `speedData` as final JSON String instead of `mainJson`.